# Convert timestamp into datetime and save to replace timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, timestamp, sql-timestamp

I'm using a SQL Server database and I have a datetime column.

```
SELECT
    [datetime]
FROM [database].[dbo].[data]

datetime
1584538200000
1584538260000
.............
1584538620000
```

Now I've already known how to convert the `timestamp` into `datetime`:

```
SELECT DATEADD(second, [datetime] / 1000, '1970-01-01')
FROM [database].[dbo].[data]
```

But my question is how to save this converted datetime to replace old timestamp in database?

Comment: Whats the datatype of your datetime column?

Comment: Thank you for reply ,it is float,but I have no idea which one is better.

Comment: If you want to store a `datetime` then the **better* datatype is `datetype` or these days `datetime2`, so if it was me I would be considering creating a new column and storing the date correctly.

Comment: Good idea,thank you!

Comment: Dear friend,can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60868459/find-and-remove-duplicate-rows-from-a-sql-server-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is preferable to store the values in the right datatype i.e., datetime or datetime2 (as suggested by @Dale K.

I would suggest you to follow below steps.

1. Create new table with just two columns: PrimaryKeycolumn, NewDateTime column

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_copy(PKColumn INT, NewDatetimeColumn DATETIME2);
```

2. Load data into data_copy from original data table

```sql
 INSERT INTO data_copy(PKColumn, NewDatetimeColumn)
 SELECT PKColumn, DATEADD(second, [datetime] / 1000, '1970-01-01')
 FROM [database].[dbo].[data];
```

3. Now, Update the datetime column to NULL values

```sql
 UPDATE [database].[dbo].[data]
    SET [datetime]= NULL;
```

4. Now, Alter the datatype to DATETIME

```sql
--IF not null set accordingly
ALTER TABLE [database].[dbo].[data] ALTER COLUMN [datetime] DATETIME2 NULL;
```

5. Now, Update the datetime values from the copy table

```sql
UPDATE d
SET d.[datetime] = c.datetimecolumn
FROM [database].[dbo].[data] AS d
JOIN [database].[dbo].[data_copy] AS c
ON d.PKColumn = c.PKColumn
```