# Find and Remove Duplicate Rows from a SQL Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime, duplicates

I'm using a SQL Server database and I have a `datetime` column datatype is `datetime`. Some rows under `datetime` column are duplicate, how can I delete the duplicate row and sort table by `datetime`?

T-SQL:

```
SELECT
    [datetime]
FROM [database].[dbo].[data]
```

Result:

```
datetime
2020-03-18 09:18:00.000
2020-03-18 09:19:00.000
2020-03-18 09:20:00.000
.............
.............
.............
2020-03-18 09:19:00.000
2020-03-18 09:20:00.000
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [datetime]
FROM [database].[dbo].[data]
ORDER BY [datetime];
```

Note:  `datetime` is a bad name for a column because it is the name of a type in SQL Server.

If you actually want to delete the rows, then use;

```
with todelete as (
      select d.*,
             row_number() over (partition by [datetime] order by [datetime]) as seqnum
      from [database].[dbo].[data]
     )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So, if you want to see the results in a particular order you need an `order by` in the query, as in the first example.

Comment: Hi friend,can you also help me with this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60874482/how-to-update-sql-server-table-after-query-sort-by-datetime